# Identify these generic looking automotive engine sensor connectors?

Tags: connector

Would you help identify these automotive engine sensor connectors?

I've found two of them on connectorexperts.com (items CE2088F, CE3175F), but the site does not provide any generic information allowing the connectors to be sourced locally. The yellow one looks similar to a TE Connector.

## Suzuki Vitara ECT Sensor Connector

[image: Suzuki Vitara ECT Sensor connector]
[image: Suzuki Vitara ECT Sensor connector]

## Suzuki Vitara EVAP Sensor Connector

[image: Suzuki Vitara EVAP Sensor connector]
[image: Suzuki Vitara EVAP Sensor connector]

## Suzuki Vitara MAF Sensor Connector

[image: Suzuki Vitara MAF Sensor connector]
[image: Suzuki Vitara MAF Sensor connector]

Comment: Often best "local" source is a scrap yard.

Comment: Oh boy. That's an automotive connector. They are a challenge.

Ask these guys: https://connectorexperts.com/ or these guys: https://www.automotiveconnectors.com/

Or, go to the parts department for the dealer for that brand of vehicle and they'll sell you a connector with wire tails already in it.

Comment: @DavideAndrea I worked for a main dealer and we did not stock connectors like that "with tails", we would repair burnt wiring looms and had to get different solutions.